# How can I easily cancel a go-rod element function?

Tags: go

I've tried several different things at this point and they all result in my code hanging at this part, specifically `n.Page.MustElement(deviceNameLoc)`.

```golang
func (n *Nable) GetDeviceName() (string, error) {
    const ( 
        deviceNameLoc string = "#deviceHeaderId > div.xtndDetailedHeaderOverview > div > span.xtndDetailedHeaderTitle"
    )
    var deviceNameNode *rod.Element
    
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        cancel()
    }()
    fmt.Println("\nAttempting to get name Element")
    deviceNameNode = n.Page.MustElement(deviceNameLoc).Context(ctx)
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        switch ctx.Err() {
        case context.DeadlineExceeded:
            fmt.Println("context timeout exceeded")
        case context.Canceled:
            fmt.Println("context cancelled by force. whole process is complete")
            return "", fmt.Errorf("NoDeviceNameElement")
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Gathered name text")
    deviceName, err := deviceNameNode.Text()
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("NoElementText: %v", err)
    }
    return deviceName, nil
}
```

This link below is what I'm currently working out of and I started with Timeout() and rod.Try(), but that's when I noticed it hanging. I added CancelTimeout() to the end, but that didn't help then I switched to the below code. cancel() always closes the go-rod browser, but won't progress my code and timeout seemingly does nothing. I'm happy to answer any further questions.

https://github.com/go-rod/go-rod.github.io/blob/main/context-and-timeout.md

I expected this code to timeout the request and provide me a timeout error so I could skip the operation. I initially got it to work on the first request it would process, but everything after that would hang and fail which is what led me to CancelTimeout() because I thought it was hanging trying to set the timeout twice.

Answer (score 0):

In the example of your link, the ctx is passed as an argument to 'page' before MustElement is called, but you do it after calling MustElement. So, when you try to cancel, your 'page' variable doesn't share the context and it hangs. Here's the example from the github link I am referring to (modified a little):

```
page := rod.New().MustConnect().MustPage()

ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
pageWithCancel := page.Context(ctx)

go func() {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    cancel()
}()

// pageWithCancel share the same 'ctx', so it  will be canceled after 2 seconds in total
pageWithCancel.MustElement("body")
```

So if you did something like this I think it would work:

```
func (n *Nable) GetDeviceName() (string, error) {
    const (
        deviceNameLoc string = "#deviceHeaderId > div.xtndDetailedHeaderOverview > div > span.xtndDetailedHeaderTitle"
    )
    var deviceNameNode *rod.Element

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    // Pass ctx to n.Page first
    pageWithContext := n.Page.Context(ctx)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        cancel()
    }()
    fmt.Println("\nAttempting to get name Element")

    deviceNameNode = pageWithContext.MustElement(deviceNameLoc)

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        switch ctx.Err() {
        case context.DeadlineExceeded:
            fmt.Println("context timeout exceeded")
        case context.Canceled:
            fmt.Println("context cancelled by force. whole process is complete")
            return "", fmt.Errorf("NoDeviceNameElement")
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Gathered name text")
    deviceName, err := deviceNameNode.Text()
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("NoElementText: %v", err)
    }
    return deviceName, nil
}
```